# Data types of dynamically generated tables

Tags: database-design, architecture, etl

First, I am a final year software engineering student. We are creating a KPI software. In there, the inputs can be either CSV, txt, xml or excel. When user enter the file to the software, we have to dynamically create a table for that particular file, to store data.

I have created a "File Import Wizard" to import files. Now the problem is creating tables. Lets say following is the data file I received as .txt

```
Name,Age,Address
Shaun,22,NY
Milan,21,Dexel RD
```

Now in the wizard I have already identified the fields of the table (columns) are `Name`, `Age`, and `Address`. But when I create the table dynamically, do I have to let the user to set the data type of each and every field?

```
eg: Name - Text
    Age - Numbers
    Address - Text
```

But since we don't know how many fields a table may have, this will be a very hard task.

what I have planned is to store all the data as 'VarChar'. Because you know, String can be converted back to other data types easily (Numbers, date).

So when the user wants to display the data in Charts, we can get the data in table and convert them into required data types and do neccasary calculations.

What is your advice on this? Please help.

Comment: *String can be converted back to other data types easily* I disagree here. Typically a conversion from Number to String and back depends on the local settings (same for a date). E.g. in Europe we mostly use dd/mm/yy as date format, while in the US mm/dd/yy is the commonly used format.

Comment: we use dd/mm/yy. That's the only date format will be used I guess. Oh, and this is for a particular company, so no need to think in global way :). Normally we follow British standards in numbering and date/time

Comment: I still would say that it is best to have the correct type in your DB.  You can still provide UI to set the data type, but already fill it in automatically based on a best-effort guess

Comment: @Robin: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I will deal with data types then. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is supposed to contain data - if your data will be treated like a string (entered like a string, displayed as a string, manipulated as a string) storing it as a string would be fine.

On the other hand, if you will be treating your data a different way at some point (say you want to select from a calendar a date), it makes sense to convert your data before putting it in the database.  In this case, if you don't convert it now, you'll be kicking the can down the road and it'll cause more headache later.

If you're in the second situation, consider reading the file header (and perhaps first row) in, and providing them with applicable choices for each row (you could even pragmatically take a best guess).  That way the user gets the final say as to what kind of data should be uploaded.  Perhaps something like this:

```
Name:   • String
        ◦ Number
        ◦ Date

Age:    ◦ String
        • Number
        ◦ Date

Address:• String
        ◦ Number
        ◦ Date
```

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for the reply and the example :). I really appreciate it :)